# A free geometry drawing program for commercial use

Tags: gratis, geometry

I'm working as a private teacher. Sometimes I need to draw some geometric figures. Is there any free program to do that? I found from the Internet that Geogebra looks good but unfortunately I'm not sure if I am allowed to use it for commercial projects. I'm a non-native English speaker. Or should I just learn for example TikZ, https://www.overleaf.com/learn/latex/TikZ_package

https://www.geogebra.org/license

I would like the program to run under Ubuntu.

Comment: Welcome to Software Recommendations SE.  On which operating system(s) should this software run?

Answer (score 1):

You can read the GeoGebra license here:
https://www.geogebra.org/license

Here is the part I believe addresses your question:

> GeoGebra and our web services are made available free of charge for
>   non-commercial users. Most of our users are students and teachers and
>   they usually fall under our non-commercial license, allowing them to
>   use and distribute GeoGebra and related materials free of charge at
>   home and in school.

Other possibly relevant software worth mentioning:

- [Blender](https://www.blender.org/) - if you want to make 3D diagrams or illustrations
- [Inkscape](https://inkscape.org/) - if you want to make 2D vector diagrams or illustrations

Those two applications are *primarily* for art/design though. If you want to create rather complex mathematical figures, I'm guessing GeoGebra would suit your needs best. I have used all three, each for different purposes.

Edit: If you are concerned with GeoGebra's license, why not ask them?

> If you are not sure whether your use is commercial or not, please just
>   get in touch with us at office@geogebra.org.

If the GeoGebra license will not allow you to use the software free of charge, you most certainly can use Blender or Inkscape for free.

Comment: Yes. But I am a private teacher and I have no school. Therefore I would like to find a similar program that can be used for commercial purposes.

Comment: @mathtutor Why not ask the publisher of the software if you can use it for your purposes?  You have nothing to lose by asking.